# Rails, precompiled assets; code changes not reflected in running app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, rake

I am developing an application with Rails 3.0 and Backbone and I tried 
asset precompilation (rake assets:precompile).

Since then any change I made in the code is not reflected in the executed application, 
in development environment.

Thank in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to pre-compile assets every time you make a change.

```
rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=development
```

Comment: I also figured out that if you just want to make any changes, the public/assets folder has to be deleted so everything will be recompiled on the fly or run rake assets:precompile in order to have everything precompiled. Thank for the quick answer!

Comment: There's a section in the Rails Guides: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#local-precompilation

Answer (score 0):

I proposed a possible cause and solution to a similar question here which relates to 
[config/application.rb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14733115/344430)  containing files to be precompiled.

Answer (score 0):

I am writing with respect to `Rails 3.2.22`

if you are facing this problem then here is solution:-

### Causes

Since you are run `rake assets:precompile` the script has created a folder `public/assets` and generated all the assets file the browser might ask for. So, when you make new changes in the js/css asset files, the requests from browser are served from `public/assets` directory.

### Two Solutions

1. `rm -df public/assets`
2. `rake assets:clean`