# Altering CSS in Rails 3.2 does not change styles without precompiling assets first

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I upgraded an app to Rails 3.2 and installed Bourbon on it. When I make a CSS change locally, for some reason I'm not seeing any change made. Only when I precompile the assets after making a change do I see it in development. Does anyone know what might be going wrong?

**Here's my `development.rb`:**

```
POP::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those
  # in config/application.rb

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Log error messages when you accidentally call methods on nil.
  config.whiny_nils = true

  # Show full error reports and disable caching
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Only use best-standards-support built into browsers
  config.action_dispatch.best_standards_support = :builtin

  # Raise exception on mass assignment protection for Active Record models
  config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict

  # Log the query plan for queries taking more than this (works
  # with SQLite, MySQL, and PostgreSQL)
  config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = 0.5

  # Do not compress assets
  config.assets.compress = false

  # Expands the lines which load the assets
  config.assets.debug = true

  # # GMail settings
  # ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  #   :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
  #   :port                 => 587,
  #   :authentication       => "plain",
  #   :enable_starttls_auto => true
  # }

end
```

**And `application.rb`:**

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

if defined?(Bundler)
  # If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
  Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
  # If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
  # Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
end

module POP
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified
    # here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Custom directories with classes and modules you want to be autoloadable.
    # config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/extras)

        # Only load the plugins named here, in the order given (default is
    # alphabetical).
    # :all can be used as a placeholder for all plugins not explicitly named.
    # config.plugins = [ :exception_notification, :ssl_requirement, :all ]

    # Activate observers that should always be running.
    # config.active_record.observers = :cacher, :garbage_collector,
    # :forum_observer

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record
    # auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names.
    # Default is UTC.
    # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from
    # config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales',
        # '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de

    # Configure the default encoding used in templates for Ruby 1.9.
    config.encoding = "utf-8"

    # Configure sensitive parameters which will be filtered from the log file.
    config.filter_parameters += [:password]

    # Use SQL instead of Active Record's schema dumper when creating the
    # database.
    # This is necessary if your schema can't be completely dumped by the
    # schema dumper,
    # like if you have constraints or database-specific column types
    # config.active_record.schema_format = :sql

    # Enforce whitelist mode for mass assignment.
    # This will create an empty whitelist of attributes available for
    # mass-assignment for all models
    # in your app. As such, your models will need to explicitly whitelist or
    # blacklist accessible
    # parameters by using an attr_accessible or attr_protected declaration.
    config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true

    # Enable the asset pipeline
    config.assets.enabled = true

    # Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets
    config.assets.version = '1.0'

    # Config spec generators
    config.generators do |g|
      g.test_framework :rspec,
        :fixtures => true,
        :view_specs => false,
        :helper_specs => false,
        :routing_specs => false,
        :controller_specs => true,
        :request_specs => true
      g.fixture_replacement :factory_girl, :dir => "spec/factories"
    end

    config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733999/how-to-avoid-precompiling-in-rails-3-1-asset-pipeline-when-changing-applicati) I hadn't found had the answer. All I needed to do was run:

```
bundle exec rake assets:clean
```