# Disable Sprockets asset caching in development on Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, ruby-on-rails-4, sprockets

Another question "[Disable Sprockets asset caching in development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16970196/disable-sprockets-asset-caching-in-development)" addresses how to disable Sprockets caching in Rails 3.2. How do you do the same thing on Rails 4? I am working on a gem that is deep in the asset pipeline and having to clear `tmp/cache/*` and restart Rails is getting tiring.

Comment: For rails 5/6 see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42954065/i-am-not-able-to-disable-the-sprockets-assets-caching-in-rails

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the Sprockets [source](https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/blob/master/lib/sprockets/railtie.rb#L117), you can see that if `cache_classes` is true then `app.assets` gets set to `app.assets.index`, and the filesystem is no longer checked.

In order to get around this in development, you can add something similar to the [following](https://gist.github.com/BenV/dc2b0f3a9f5c755cadb1) to your `development.rb` configuration:

```
# Sprockets configuration: prevent sprockets from caching assets in development
# when cache_classes is set to true
sprockets_env = nil
config.assets.configure do |env|
  sprockets_env = env

  # Sprockets environment configuration goes here
  # env.js_compressor  = :uglifier # or :closure, :yui
  # env.css_compressor = :sass   # or :yui
end

if config.cache_classes
  config.after_initialize do
    Rails.application.assets = sprockets_env
  end
end
```

This essentially grabs a reverence to the Sprockets::Environment object before it is overwritten by the Sprockets::Index one, and allows the filesystem to be checked for new assets even when `cache_classes` is true. This seems to work for us in development, so hopefully it helps someone else out as well.

Comment: Ahh, we are currently still on Rails 4.0, so we will need to re-investigate when we go to upgrade. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: For rails 5/6 see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42954065/i-am-not-able-to-disable-the-sprockets-assets-caching-in-rails