# Rails 4: How to disable pre-erb assets cache in dev environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

Using Rails 4, Unicorn and Ngnix in dev. I have a `facebook.js.erb` file with this code:

```
FB.init({
    appId: '<%= Rails.application.config.facebook.id %>'
});
```

When I change the value of `Rails.application.config.facebook.id` in `development.rb` and reload `facebook.js` in the browser, it does not reflect the change.

Here are all the things I tried that fail to update `facebook.js`:

- Restart Unicorn
- Restart Nginx
- Clear browser cache
- [Disable Sprockets asset caching in development on Rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22979839/disable-sprockets-asset-caching-in-development-on-rails-4)
- `touch facebook.js.erb`

The only thing that works is to make some modification to `facebook.js.erb` (eg. add a space). There is obviously some kind of checksum caching happening pre-erb. How do I disable it?

Comment: Have you tired killing sprockets altogether?

Comment: Just did, - it didn't work.

Comment: @Arman did you find a solution?