# Disable the sprockets assets caching in rails 5+

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, sprockets

I have tried a lot to disable sprockets asset cache in rails but no vain. I have tried to configure development.rb but it is not working at at all.
I am using this code to disable cache generation

```
config.assets.cache_store = :null_store  # Disables the Asset cache
config.sass.cache = false  # Disable the SASS compiler cache
```

ruby version=2.3.3
rails version=5.0.1
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the [Rails docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#assets-cache-store), add the following code block to your environments/development.rb

```
config.assets.configure do |env|
  env.cache = ActiveSupport::Cache.lookup_store(:null_store)
end
```